# JSP set a variable with GET vars

Tags: jsp, jstl

I know this is a simple syntax thing, but I can't figure it out.

```
/* url = index.jsp?topic=whatever */
Path <%= request.getParameter('topic') %> <!-- works -->
<c:set var="myVar" value="${ request.getParameter('topic') }" />
<c:out value="${myVar}" /> <!-- doesn't print out onto my web page -->
```

All I want to do is set `myVar` with the GET parameter 'topic'. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the request param with:

```
<c:set var="myVar" value="${param.topic}" />
```

and then print it

```
<c:out value="${myVar}" />
```

More info:

- [Getting request parameters using JSTL](http://exampledepot.8waytrips.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core/getparam.html)

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. I was hoping it could help me with request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI) but they don't list the jstl equivalent of that...

Answer (score 3):

This is because scriptlets in <%= %> are java expressions whereas those in ${ } are EL expressions. A different language. To get the value of a parameter, you would do: ${param.topic}

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get it with

```
${param.topic}
```

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-custom012.htm#BNATJ) says

> One external data source that a value attribute can refer to is an implicit object.
>
> [...]
>
> `param` - A Map of the request parameters for this request, keyed by parameter name